# Proving $\operatorname{ker} T$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\operatorname{range}T$ is a subspace of $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My question is as follows: Suppose $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces, and let $T: V \longrightarrow W$ be a linear transformation.

Show that $\ker T$ is a subspace of $V$.

Show that $\operatorname{range} T$ is a subspace of $W$.

Most of my problem here is I don't think I fully understand the concept of the kernel and the range.  I know that the kernel relates to a null space, and the range to the column space...  I also know that I have to show that each (the kernel and the range) must contain the zero vector, preserve vector addition and scalar multiplication.

The kernel is then all the solutions to $Ax= \vec 0$, so the zero vector must be there?

I don't know how to proceed from there and we have hardly worked with the kernel and the range in class, so I really don't know where to go with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

To show that $\ker T$ is a subspace of $V$, we need to show that it has the following properties:

- Has $0$
- Is additively closed
- Is scalar multiplicatively closed

Clearly $T(0)=0$. So we need only show additive and scalar multiplicative closure.

**Additive closure:** We want to show that if $a,b\in \ker(T)$ then $a+b\in\ker(T)$. E.g. $T(a)=0,T(b)=0\implies T(a+b)=0$. This follows from the property of *additivity*, $T(a+b)=T(a)+T(b)=0+0=0$, and hence $a+b\in\ker T$.

**Scalar multiplicative closure:** We want to show that if $a\in\ker(T)$ then $ka\in\ker(T)$ where $k\in\Bbb F$. So $T(a)=0$ and by the property of homogeneity(of degree $1$) we have that $0=k0=kT(a)=T(ka)$ and hence $ka\in\ker(T)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $F=\text{ker}(T)$. Then $0_V\in S$ because $T(0_V)=0_W$ and if $x,y\in F$ ($x,y$ are elements of $V$) then $\alpha x+\beta y\in F$ for all scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ because
$$
T(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha T(x)+\beta T(y)=\alpha 0_W+\beta 0_W=0_W+0_W=0_W
$$
with the first equality above uses the linearity of $T$. Similarly, let $G=\text{range}(T)$. Then $0_W\in G$ because there exists an element in $V$ (i.e. $0_V$) such that this element is mapped by $T$ to $0_W$. And finally, if $u,v\in W$ are s.t. $w,w'\in G$, then $\alpha  w+\beta w'$ is also in $G$. This is because $w,w'\in G$ implies that there exist $v,v'$ in $V$ s.t. $w=T(v)$ and $w'=T(v')$ and so
$$
\alpha w+\beta w'=\alpha T(v)+\beta T(v')=T(\underbrace{\alpha v+\beta v'}_{\in V})\in\text{range}(T)=G.
$$

Comment: @BolzWeir  How do I actually show something is in the $range(T)$.  For the kernel I see that we had to show T had to equal zero for each of the properties.  But, how do you show that $u+v$ is a linear combination of the columns of A, given $u$ and $v$ are in the $range(T)$?

Comment: @Theresa for $w\in W$, we say $w$ is in the range of $T$ iff there is something in $V$, say $v\in V$, such that $T$ maps $v$ to $w$. In symbols, $\forall w\in W,w\in\text{range}(T)\iff\exists v\in V, T(v)=w$.